# Getting NotSerializableException: sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D

Tags: java, serialization

I am getting NotSerializableException from quite a while.
the full error is like this

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at SOM_thread1.run(soms1.java:354)
```

the error is on out.writeObject(g);
the full code is as follows

```
public class soms1 extends JApplet implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -743443566771258883L;

// class of weights and samples which performs operations on the SOM
public static Screen screen = new Screen();

// Socket Connection 
private static Socket clientSocket = null;
private static PrintStream os = null;
private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;


// thread responsible for updating Screen
static public SOM_thread1 thread = null;

Toolkit tool;

public void init() {
    String sentence;
    tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
        thread = new SOM_thread1(clientSocket);
        setup_applet();
        setup_radios();
        setup_layout();

        screen.init_Screen();

        thread.init();
        thread.start();

        inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        sentence = inputLine.readLine();
        if (clientSocket != null && os != null
                && sentence.equals("server:apl")) {
            thread.set_state(2);
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

}

class SOM_thread1 extends Thread implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int state = -1;
int MAX_ITER = 0;
float t;
float T_INC;
private ObjectOutputStream out = null;
private Socket clientSocket = null;
public transient Graphics g = null;

public SOM_thread1(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
}
/*Updates the class Screen according the to values retrieved from the user interface*/
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // Send data to server
        try {
            g = soms1.screen.getGraphics();
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(g);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Allow other operations
        yield();
    } // while(true)

}
}
```

please notify which object i should serialize
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't (usefully) serialize a `Thread` subclass.  The `Thread` superclass includes state that is inherently not serializable.

And the actual exception is happening because this line:

```
          out.writeObject(g);
```

is explicitly trying to serialize a `sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D` instance.  It is not serializable.  The best you could do would be to attempt to create a new `Graphics` object in the context where you are deserializing things.

FWIW, there is quite a lot about your code that makes little sense to me.  What is the point of serializing a `Graphics` object?  What are you actually trying to achieve?

---

> I am trying to send the graphic data to server via graphic object. for that i used Screen.getGraphics() method provided by sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D. screen is only a display method which generates graphical map.

Basically, what you are trying to do is impossible.  The state of the Graphics object (i.e. the stuff displayed on the screen) cannot be retrieved via the Graphics APIs in a form that would allow you to reconstruct it on a new device.

You should be serializing the source data that you rendered on the device in its original form, and re-rendering it after you have de-serialized it.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I am trying to send the graphic data to server via graphic object. for that i used Screen.getGraphics() method provided by sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D. screen is only a display method which generates graphical map. i am trying to solve this from about a week now

Comment: Well, basically, that won't work.  You will need to find some other way to encode the graphics data so the you can send it to the server.

Comment: can you Suggest any way from which i can serialize the object before sending?

Comment: No I can't.  A Graphics object doesn't have APIs that allow you to read back the state of the graphics device and what it is displaying.  What you are trying to do is >>impossible<<.

Comment: ok, i guess i should try another approach. Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're writing object `g` returned by `Screen.getGraphics()` method which I assume (from the stacktrace) returns an instance of class `sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D`.

If you look at its signature

```
public final class SunGraphics2D extends java.awt.Graphics2D implements sun.awt.ConstrainableGraphics, java.lang.Cloneable, sun.java2d.DestSurfaceProvider {
```

you'll find out that it doesn't implement `Serializable` and it is `final`, so it seems you're out of luck...

Comment: can you suggest any fix for this error? of just to suppress it so that i can send the object?

Comment: Suppressing the exception won't help you since it won't serialize the graphics object and you can send only a `Serializable` object.

Comment: so is there any way i can serialize the object before sending?

Comment: `SunGraphics2D`? No. Question is - what does that object contain? How are you creating it? Are you able to separate the data you want from the graphics object?

Comment: this is code for screen from where the object is getting its values thanks for help [link]https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7332825352612901!298&authkey=!APi_-JIg80WUIpw&ithint=folder%2c